# How can I fix 'Cannot read properties of undefined' error when accessing prop values in a child component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await, react-props

I'm trying to access the value of a array `fileList` that I pass as a prop to a component `<FileDisplay prop={filesList}/>`, but when I try to read a property of the array `{JSON.stringify(props.prop[0].name)}` I get an error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

but I can read `JSON.stringify(props.prop[0])` without getting any errors.

Also, if I first run the code with `{JSON.stringify(props.prop[0].name)}` commented out and then uncomment it and save the code, react compiles again and I am able to read the value of `props.prop[0].name`.

From my understanding, the code is trying to read the `props.prop[0].name` before the promise returns and `filesList` value is set. Is there a way to fix this?

```
export default function Home() {

    const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
    const [ filesList, setFilesList ] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
      const getData = async () => {
        const listFiles = await listAll(ref(storage, 'files'))
        const data = await  Promise.all(listFiles.items.map(async (itemRef) => {
          const response = getMetadata(ref(storage, 'files/'+ itemRef.name))
          return response
        }))
        setFilesList(data)
      }
      getData()
    }, [])

 return (
    <div>
      
      <div>
        <FileDisplay prop={filesList}/>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  )
```

```
export default function FileDisplay(props) {    
  return (
    <div>
       <h2>LIST OF FILES</h2>
        <p>{JSON.stringify(props.prop)}</p>
        <p>-----------------------</p>
        <p>{JSON.stringify(props.prop[0])}</p>
        <p>-----------------------</p>
        <p>{JSON.stringify(props.prop[0].name)}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I've tried to read the variable but I still can't access the properties

Comment: Welcome to SO Lucas. There are 2 ways in mind that can resolve the issue, the first one is to use something like the optional chaining operator, `?.` to access the property `name` only if it's defined on the object. The other one is to conditionally render the `FileDisplay` component only if the `filesList` is not an emtpy array. Like so: `{filesList.length > 0 && <FileDisplay prop={filesList}/>}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue may be related to timing, specifically, the FileDisplay component is being created before the filesList state has been populated.

The `getData` method is async so your component will continue to load while it waits for a response. This means the FileDisplay component is likely to be initially created with a props value equal to [] (`fileList` default value) which will result in `props.prop[0]` returning undefined.

I would suggest loading the FileDisplay component conditionally:

Replace

```
<FileDisplay prop={filesList}/>
```

with

```
{filesList.length && <FileDisplay prop={filesList}/>}
```

This assumes that fileList will always have at least one element. If this is not the case then you should replace the `filesList.length` check with another state variable that indicates the fetch of files has completed. e.g.

```
const [ isFetching, setIsFetching ] = useState<boolean>(true)
```

then within `getData` set `setIsFetching(false)` just before `setFilesList(data)`

You would also need to modify the FileDisplay component to handle an empty array in props parameter.